# VSIX - Creating a submenu - how do I populate the submenu "replacement item"

Tags: c#, submenu, vsix

I am creating a VSIX package and I have added an item to the context menu for the Project node (context menu which shows up when you right-click on a project in solution explorer).

My item is a menu and I have that working. I've been reading this article: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166492.aspx

And it says that in order to populate the menu, I need to create an item on the menu that will be replaced by a list of items at run-time.

That's all well and good. When I follow this article exactly, I get a list of projects and I can choose one to be the Startup project of my solution.

But what the article fails to mention is how this list gets populated. There's no mention of it in the article - it just seems to work by some kind of voodoo. And I don't want a list of projects, I want to populate the list of items with something else. I've been banging my head on my desk for 2 days now and I can't seem to figure it out.

How do I replace the replacement item with my own custom list of items?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do this and agree the example is not obvious.  I too expected to just populate a list of menu items somewhere but it was not that simple.  I have posted my sample of the demo up on [github](https://github.com/fpw23/DynamicMenuItems) which may help.  In my case I wanted to add a dynamic menu list to the right click context menu on certain solution explorer items (folders and projects).  I needed this for a feature I am working on in my T4 scaffolding extension [T4 Awesome](https://www.t4awesome.com/).

The thing that finally made it click for me was figuring out there was not a list I added my menus to, instead Visual Studio calls a set of methods you provide over and over again until you tell it to stop.  Each call you set a different menu item.  Here is the summary from the readme on github which explains it a bit more.

> You create the menus and buttons in the vsct file like normal except
>   for the dynamic one, for that one you have to add the command flag:
>
> ```
> <CommandFlag>DynamicItemStart</CommandFlag>
> ```
>
> this signals to visual studio that your menu will be dynamic.
>
> You build a class that will manage what is shown on the menu. From the
>   ms example they built a class called DynamicMenu and its job is to
>   register the dynamic menu button and provide the three methods vs will
>   call into when it encounters the button:
>   OnBeforeQueryStatusDynamicItem, IsValidDynamicItem,
>   OnInvokedDynamicItem. When you right click and invoke the context
>   menu, vs hits your dynamic button and then calls these methods over
>   and over allow you to set as many menu items as you need. The
>   IsValidDynamicItem method controls the number of times by returning
>   false when you are done. The OnBeforeQueryStatusDynamicItem lets you
>   set the menu text for the button. And the OnInvokedDynamicItem lets
>   you respond the to user clicking the menu item.

Comment: Interesting. I actually solved this in a completely different way. All I did was add MenuCommands to the CommandService starting with the ID of the replacement item and then increment by 1 and it seems to have automatically just picked them up - presumably based on the IDs.

Comment: hmm, so does it work if you clear them out and start over?  In my case I needed to show a dynamic set of menu items based on context (if they are right clicking a folder or a project)

Comment: I haven't tried that. It's working now and I've moved on to something else. But it would be interesting to see. I am probably adding a whole bunch of tools that aren't actually being used.